# SQLAlchemy getting default's column label name out from result set

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to select data from the **user** and **account** tables. there are id and name column which exists in both tables. so SQLAlchemy applies labels while querying into the database.
for e.g

```
query=(User.name, User.id, Account.name, Account.id).join(Account, Account.user_id = User.id)
print(query)

select user.name as user_name, user.id as user_id, account.name as account_name, account.id as account_id from user, join account on account.user_id = user.id;
```

when iterating over results each row contains only id and name attribute. so either I can get user name or account name when I will access it

```
result = session(query).all()
for row in result:
    print(row.name, row.id)
```

**I know i can apply label to the column to give alias name but I don't want to manually apply a label to each column.**